# Existence (or reason of lack) of simple cmos LIFO registers IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos, stack

There's a project I'm working on that needs a *simple* LIFO register.

What I mean by simple is to support the PUSH & POP operations, and I guess EMPTY and FULL indicators.

I must be searching with the wrong keywords on  Google, because searches such as "CMOS LIFO register" come with educational papers, and not ICs.

[The 7400 series IC list I'm sticking to](http://raven1.magix.net/List%20of%207400%20series%20integrated%20circuits.pdf) doesn't list an IC that does those.

While I can simply accept that there's no such IC, that would be surprising, as the demand, should be sufficient **(I'm not a market nor electronics expert, I'm simply guessing)**. So, if there's no CMOS stack register out there , *why* exactly ?

So I guess my questions are :

- Is there any basic CMOS LIFO register or equivalent ?
- If there doesn't exist such IC, *why* ?

Sorry if my question is just a result of my poor Googling skills, by the way.

Comment: while shift registers are easy to implement, stacks are not, would be my guess. Also, a FIFO is in far more common demand; whatever needs a LIFO typically is complex logic enough to be able to address memory and would hence work with a RAM chip. (that's by the way what I'd recommend in this case, have a glue logic CPLD + a RAM IC)

Comment: Discrete CMOS is pretty much obsolete in general, vs microcontrollers. I think FiFos exist but lifo is a bit more complex.

Comment: The main reason is lack of demand.  The only place such operations are usually needed is within a processor - nobody designs processors using SSI.  You can easily implement it in an FPGA if you needed it.

Comment: I know that FPGAs are now the way to go for processing units. But as my project is a self-educating one (and once finished probably an educating tool) so , i'd really like to stick to discrete, to ease learning (not toward college students, but more toward curious high-schoolers).

Comment: You could use a static RAM chip addressed by a synchronous (clocked) binary up/down counter. The counters are often just 4 bit, but it's easy to cascade two or more to address more than 16 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A universal shift register IC can implement the function you're thinking of. For example, the 74194. No empty/full indicator as that would require a counter. Push/pop are left/right shift.

Comment: I though of that as well. To create the empty/full indicators would indeed require a counter. The empty/full signals could also be useful in avoiding bottom data erasure (being shifted out of the shift register). It would indeed be my solution if LIFOs are unavailable. I am going to wait the night for answers to come before reviewing and accepting one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an SRAM and an up/down counter. Might need a bus switch as well for reading. How big of a stack are you trying to build?